# I have connection to database in OOP php with PDO, then Connection send me a message

Tags: php

```
pdo)){ 
try{ $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->db;$this->username,$this->password"); 
$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
}catch (PDOException $e){ 
   // report error message 
   echo $e->getMessage(); 
} 
}
 } 
} 
$db = new Database(); ?>
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to
>   database 'crud'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s about English translation, not programming

Comment: Show all your code ...because user and pass is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Your code should as below ,if you still get error probably pass,user or host is incorrect

```
class Database
{
      private $username='root';

      private $password='host';

     private $host='localhost';


     private $db='mydb';

     private $connect;

     function __construct()
     {


           $this->connect= new 
           PDO("mysql:host=$this>host;dbname=$this->db",$this->username,$this->password); 
         $this>connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, 
          PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
}catch (PDOException $e){ 
   // report error message 
   echo $e->getMessage(); 
} 
}
 } 


     } 


  public function pdo()
  {

        return $this->connect;
   }


    public function __destruct()
    {
         $this->connect=null;

     }
}


$db = new Database();

$connect=$db->pdo();
```